# Word of a list with most repeated vowels? More pythonic solution?

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary, key

Here is my current solution which seems to be operating correctly aside from I am not sure what the code does if two or more words are tied, I need to work on that as well.

```
def most_repeating_vowel(word):

    vowels = {"a":0,"e":0,"i":0,"o":0,"u":0}
    for i in word:
        if i in vowels:
            vowels[i]+=1
    return max(vowels.values())
       
def most_repeating_word(seq):
    return max(seq, key=most_repeating_vowel)

mylist = ["giraffe","elephant","ox","yyyyyyy","iiiii"]

most_repeating_word(mylist)
```

Is there a more pythonic way I can handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I like using `str.count`:

```
max(mylist, key=lambda w: max(map(w.count, 'aeiou')))
```

Benchmark with your example data:

```
Round 1  Round 2  Round 3 
16.1 us  16.0 us  15.5 us  Stef
 5.2 us   5.0 us   5.1 us  KellyBundy
```

And with longer words (each word multiplied by 1000):

```
Round 1  Round 2  Round 3 
1466 us  1476 us  1480 us  Stef
  71 us    71 us    71 us  KellyBundy
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFNb9swDIbv/hVEgMBya3gL2g1DgFy6427rMQgMxaYbofqCLMd1/3wmSk7rouh08AdJPS/50k7@ZPTdL@sul84ZBV4oFB6Essb5@S@b/xojJTZeGN1nWYsdPHrsmJqk6H2xzQAo1phB@1qZ3tcOLXKPbX02I0o2xhqABnZLVPWbbqAL@Zh26AenQfEX1uzPB@iMgzMIDTlHYYacqhY1Sb6EZ5x2X2oXqd8/KOX0MOh2Wnb9BUxydWw5jNuU4ZaNVRQo3zopArcbdNOHiciLcqGQFI@om5Pi7vkNrQd1RFeC5EeUJU2neOrD98TZ79PINY0c4YeQo4ijiOP6CdmmhPvZTeuE9uyGRR6sQcRa8aHW3W6oVyqnJFHLIEc1r8KyqEKBfmaGXkInafks@bCNt662XcfYpVcB3@bA9XpfcWtRt8wXc@jaJxmZhibFIqAIXNW15grrulgMFdxNemTL6kk43nW4Klco0Z649uHTvITHlE74EnRWh@yz7T@@hxM29zdssIV1CzmtIG7YbyFf31ebDoYe8mAh83ADG/wZLHsH7UcKBki0cCTvEvsQ4f9Dt5/Bl8s/))

```
from timeit import timeit
import collections

def Stef(mylist):
  def count_most_repeated_vowel(w):
    c = collections.Counter(w)
    return max(c[v] for v in 'aeiou')
  return max(mylist, key=count_most_repeated_vowel)

def KellyBundy(mylist):
  return max(mylist, key=lambda w: max(map(w.count, 'aeiou')))

funcs = Stef, KellyBundy

def benchmark(mylist, number, label, format):
  tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
  for r in range(1, 4):
    print(*(label % i for i in range(1, r+1)))
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
      t = timeit(lambda: func(mylist), number=number) / number
      ts.append(t)
      print(*(map(format, ts)), func.__name__)
    print()

mylist = ["giraffe","elephant","ox","yyyyyyy","iiiii"]
benchmark(mylist, 50000, 'Round %d ', lambda t: '%4.1f us ' % (t * 1e6))
benchmark([w * 1000 for w in mylist], 500, 'Round %d ', lambda t: '%4d us ' % (t * 1e6))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `collections.Counter`, which is a subclass of `dict` used to count things:

```py
import collections

mylist = ["giraffe","elephant","ox","yyyyyyy","iiiii"]

def count_most_repeated_vowel(w):
  c = collections.Counter(w)
  return max(c[v] for v in 'aeiou')

print(max(mylist, key=count_most_repeated_vowel))
# 'iiiii'
```

- [documentation on `collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)